# Making a custom editor with Windows XAML RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm working on creating a text editor with a custom keyboard using C# and the XAML RichEditBox.  I need to be able to emulate functions which would normally be handled by the built-in keyboard.  I would love any help understanding the following:

- Preventing the keyboard from appearing (there's a property to prevent it on programmatic focus, but not on user focus.  I can also hide it by setting the IsReadOnly property, but then I can't modify the text)
- Handling backspace.  There is a Delete function on the Document.Selection, but it works as Delete, not Backspace (pulls from the wrong direction)
- Need to prevent horizontal scroll.  Text just scrolls off the side even with HorizontalScrollVisibility set to Disabled.  Not sure what else to do here.

Sorry to basically cram three questions into one, but it seemed like someone with the right knowledge would have an easier time this way.  Thanks!

To simplify things, here's my current properties:

> VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"

Comment: What exactly do you want backspace to do?

Comment: I want it to behave normally, i.e. remove the character to the left (assuming left-to-right layout).  Delete removes the character to the right.  Since I'm making a keyboard from scratch I need to implement this myself.  I don't want to manipulate the contained string.  I'm using Document methods.  Here is what I have tried:  
`EditBox.Document.Selection.Delete(Windows.UI.Text.TextRangeUnit.Character, 1);`

Comment: OK.  Got that figured out too.  Turns out you just Delete -1 characters!  Yikes.

Answer (score 0):

Need to prevent horizontal scroll:

I am guessing that this RichEditBox is contained inside a ScrollViewer.  You set HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch" which says take the entire layout of the parent element.  Set this to Center, Left or Right.

Comment: I haven't put it into a ScrollViewer though the default template may use one.  Changing the RichEditBox to Center simply makes it shrink in size and align to the center.  I just discovered another scroll-related property but it didn't help either:  
`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"`  
I need it to word wrap!

Comment: Then you need to post your entire layout.  If I just take a <Grid> and put a <RichEditBox> inside I don't get Horizontal scroll and my text wraps.  Where I have seen your behavior is when something is put inside a ScrollViewer which has infinite horizontal and vertical space.

Comment: Grrr.  Just found it!  `TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"`  It still doesn't wrap though.  It clearly does think it's in a wider parent control.

Comment: thanks for helping!  It is actually a simply RichEditBox inside a Grid:  
`    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".55*" />
            <RowDefinition Height=".45*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichEditBox  />
`  
Properties omitted since they are already above and I ran out of characters!

Comment: So it turns out that the right answer for wrapping is `TextWrapping="Wrap"`  It's a non-English language so that must explain it.  Way too difficult!